# Javascript button onclick get input value and submit post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, post

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    <select id="item" name="item">
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="3">Pink</option>
        <option value="4">Black</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="addItem();" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

How can I use javascript to call the `addItem()` function and send a post request to `test.php` with the value of the username as username, password as password, and item as item?

**EDIT:**

This is the only code in my `addItem();` function so far:

```
$.post("http://test.com/test.php",{username:username, password:pword, item:item}, function(data) {
    $('#message').html(data);
});
```

However, I'm wondering, how can I grab the data from all of the input fields and put it into the code I have above? This is because the function is called through a button and NOT a submit button.

Comment: read about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: if you are using form then I guess `addItem();` can be used for validation purpose, else as Arun suggested, `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` or `$.get()` will help you out. in that case form is not necessary.

Comment: @Aman Please look at my edit, I'm already using `$.post()`, I just need to find out how to grab the data.

Comment: @user2898075 pretty simple... use `$('#username').val()` and so on, where `username` is id attribute of input field. same applies to other field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the data, jQuery has beautiful function inside. based upon your edited question you can try this :

```
var username = $("#username").val();  
var pword = $("#password").val();  
var item = $("#item option:selected" ).text();
// you can check the validity of username and password here
$.post("http://test.com/test.php",{username:username, password:pword, item:item},        
function(data) {
   $('#message').html(data);
});
```

(again, if you are following this way then there is no use of `form` tag.)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can send the form as simply as doing:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $.post('path/to/server/file', $(this).serialize(),function(response){
       /* do something with returned data from server*/
   });
   return false; /* prevent browser submitting form*/
});
```

`$.post` is a shortcut method of `$.ajax`

[jQuery $.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[jQuery $.post() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm executing the function upon a button a click, and not on a submission. I've made an edit to my question.

Comment: well when you originally posted question you didn't provide any code. You can still serialize all data using `$('form').serialize()`. WOuld be better to give form an ID and use that as selector. Really not clear what your updated question is

Comment: @charlietfl serialize.. nice way to go through, is it able to serialize all the form element ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="your.php" onSubmit="return addItem()">
```

This should do it

then in js

```
function addItem() {
//whatever you want to do
return true;
}
```

=============================================================

I see you are using Ajax, if you want to do it, then you should do the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "#yoursubmitbuttonID", function(e){
var password = $("#password").val();
var username = $("#username").val();
//send Ajax here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give a form name and a action url, then use form.sumit() method to post form data

```
<form method='post' name='myform' action='test.php'>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItem() {
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```